# only select or return value 3 string from table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a string data in my table. I want to select only 5 word from the data. For example:

```
I have a ball
```

but I want to select only

```
I have a
```

How to do this in sql?

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: i act already did SUM(LENGTH(meeting_series_agenda_act_desc) - LENGTH(REPLACE(meeting_series_agenda_act_desc, ' ', '')) + 1) which return string sum . but after that i want to only select 50 word from that where i stuck

Comment: Please add this code in your question also

Comment: Can you count to five?

Answer (score 0):

If you want first 3 words from your column you can use `substring_index` which is a string function

```
select substring_index(col,' ',3) /* change 3 to 5 for first 5 words */
from demo
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fe791/1)

To get remaining string after first 3 words you can use following

```
SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(col,SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,' ',3),' '))
FROM demo
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fe791/2)

Comment: thanks ! but what if i want to select the rest of the word after 3 ? meaning "ball"